# Scanf não funciona mesmo forçando a ignorar os espaços

Tags: c, c++, scanf

Estou tentando fazer um programinha simples pra começar a mexer com C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    
    char nome[100];
    char dataNascimento[10];
    char telefone[11];
    char endereco[200];
    char email[100];
    char nomeAnimal[100];
    char especie[100];
    char raca[100];
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf("Nome: \n"); 
    scanf(" %s", &nome);
    
    printf("Data de Nascimento: \n");   
    scanf(" %s", &dataNascimento);
    
    printf("Endereço: \n"); 
    scanf(" %s", &endereco);
    
    printf("E-mail: \n");   
    scanf(" %s", &email);
    
    printf("Telefone: \n"); 
    scanf(" %s", &telefone);
    
    printf("Nome Animal: \n");  
    scanf(" %s", &nomeAnimal);
    
    printf("Espécie: \n");  
    scanf(" %s", &especie);
    
    printf("Raça: \n"); 
    scanf(" %s", &raca);           
    
    printf("Cliente Cadastrado Com Sucesso!");  
    
    return 0;
}
```

Quando eu informo uma palavra na linha do nome, o programa funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando insiro duas palavras, o scanf entre Data de Nascimento e Endereço não funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma observação que não foi comentada nas respostas é sobre o `&`. Ele não é necessário no `scanf` quando o objetivo é ler uma `string / vetor`, pois a variável do vetor já aponta para o endereço, isto é, se temos `vetor[10]` então `vetor == &vetor[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Essa é bem simples, o problema é que você esta trabalhando com strings(array de caracteres) e está utilizando o scanf para receber o input, e o problema é a [definição do scanf](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-scanf-and-gets-in-c/):

`scanf()`: Vai ler todo o input na linha até encontrar um **espaço**, newline ou End of file(EOF)

Então normalmente vai ser recomendado o uso do gets() pois ele é especificamente para isso, diferente do scanf() que é para uso geral:

`gets()`: Vai ler todo o input até encontrar ou um newline ou o fim do arquivo, considerando espaços como parte da string

Mas o principal ponto, como mencionado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf) é que tanto o uso do scanf como do gets não são ideais para programas a longo prazo, pois ambos não tem um buffer de proteção contra overflow, a alternativa com essa proteção seriam o fgets(), que pode ser utilizado como no exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[30];
    printf("Input:\n");
    fgets(str, 10, stdin);
    // vai receber apenas os primeiros 10 caracteres digitados (você coloca o numero que precisar)
    printf("Output: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

ex:
Input:
1234567891011121314151617181920

Output: 123456789

Entretanto, se ainda quiser ou precisar muito usar o scanf, é possivel criar uma exceção dentro desse scanf para ele ignorar espaços como condição de parada usando, `%[^\n]s`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema está ocorrendo pois a função `scanf` lê a entrada até encontrar um espaço. Então, ao digitar duas palavras separadas, é como se você estivesse dando 2 valores ao programa.

Para que você consiga armazenar mais de uma palavra em uma mesma variável você pode utilizar a função [fgets](https://www.pucsp.br/%7Eso-comp/cursoc/aulas/c970.html) no lugar.
Ex.:

```c
printf("Nome: \n");
fgets(nome,100,stdin);
```

Onde:

- **nome** = a variável onde o valor será armazenado
- **100** = o número máximo de caracteres que será armazenado
- **stdin** = o dispositivo de entrada (normalmente o teclado)

Agora, após realizar esta substituição, você poderá armazenar nomes com mais de uma palavra (separadas por espaços) em uma única variável.